# App Store app prepare issues,How can i fix it provide copyright information?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I prepared my application for the apple store test flight, but I can't find how to solve the problem I added in the image.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find it under the detail of the version in the app store tab, I wanted to answer it myself in case anyone has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the 2023 Version

For Copy Right - It's under the App Store Tab - General Menu - Next to the version.

Contact information is only needed if your app requires sign-in.
Uncheck the box ***Sign in required*** if not needed.